# SQL Server 2019 Memory-Optimized Tempdb Metadata doesn't eliminate PAGELATCH_* waits on GAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, tempdb, sql-server-2022

We are using SQL Server 2019 with a third party application that makes heavy use of the tempdb database.

And we have lot of PAGELATCH_xx waits on tempdb.

Memory-Optimized Tempdb Metadata is enabled.

Just checked that this query returns 1:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsTempdbMetadataMemoryOptimized');
```

But we still have tempdb contention.

Example of [script from Madeira Toolbox](https://github.com/MadeiraData/MadeiraToolbox/blob/master/Utility%20Scripts/Identify%20Tempdb%20Contention.sql) output:
[image: script output]

Is this expected behavior?

What could be done to eliminate PAGELATCH_xx waits on tempdb?

Should increasing the number of tempdb files help? (the documentation says yes, but tried increasing it from 16 to 32, it doesn't seem to make much of a difference).

Should faster tempdb storage (with low latency) help? (I think not, but I can be wrong)

Found an interesting presentation: [SQL Server 2022: System Page Latch Concurrency Enhancements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2FYyOk27ZxM)
Will upgrading to SQL Server 2022 solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

> Will upgrading to SQL Server 2022 solve the problem?

Most likely, yes.

You are experiencing *allocation contention* on GAM pages. The *Tempdb Metadata Memory Optimized* feature helps with (some) *metadata contention*, which has different causes and solutions.

You can find all the details in the Microsoft blog, "[Improve scalability with system page latch concurrency enhancements in SQL Server 2022](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/blog/2022/07/21/improve-scalability-with-system-page-latch-concurrency-enhancements-in-sql-server-2022/)" by David Pless. Some quotes:

> SQL Server **tempdb** contention is near completely addressed in SQL Server 2022 and these benefits are on by default. With these improvements in SQL Server 2022 we allow concurrent updates to the GAM and SGAM under a shared latch rather than using the update latch. This improvement erases nearly all tempdb contention allowing parallel threads to be able to modify the GAM and SGAM pages

> If concurrent GAM and concurrent SGAM updates are some of the last areas of contention, do we still need the best practices to maintain multiple data files for **tempdb**?
>
> Out of the gate, we are going to continue recommending the same best practices, but we may adjust if we find that it is no longer required through customer feedback.

Please do read the whole document carefully.

On SQL Server 2019, the best you can do is increase the number of files toward one per scheduler.